# How do I customize React Native's AwesomeProject?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'd like to use React Native's AwesomeProject as a jumping off point for my own app.

[React Native's Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#the-react-native-cli%20%22React%20Native%20Getting%20Started%20%7C%20The%20React%20Native%20CLI) instructs users to download the the CLI and `init AwesomeProject`.

I'm looking to move these files to my own repo's directory. However, once moved, the build no longer works within the new directory.

How do I move the files and customize (i.e. rename the Xcode project, etc.) `AwesomeProject` or any of the react-native-cli's starter kits such as `ReactNativeWebHelloWorld`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to init the project with react-native init anyNameYouWant, It's no the starter kit, is a way react-cli bind al the projects to your name folder.